# WebView Issue in Expo SDK 50 - Successful Download in Expo Go, but Fails in Built App

Tags: webview, expo

I recently upgraded my Expo project to SDK version 50. Prior to the update, I had a working implementation where I could download documents using WebView in Expo SDK 48. However, after the update to SDK 50, I am encountering issues with downloading documents via WebView.

Despite various attempts to resolve the problem, I have been unsuccessful. Interestingly, when testing with Expo Go, document downloads work correctly. However, when accessing the app through the built APK, API communication is successful, but document downloads fail, displaying a message indicating the issue.

import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(webViewSource);

As seen in the code above, I have successfully implemented document downloads using the expo-web-browser module in Expo Go and built app. However, the original WebView-based document downloads still do not work when running the built APK, despite successful API communication.

The issue is occurring on Android.
I have been unable to identify the root cause of the issue. Please help me.

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "tablet",
    "slug": "tablet-web",
    "version": "1.3.3",
    "orientation": "landscape",
    "icon": "./assets/icon/appstore.png",
    "scheme": "tabletwebdev",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0,
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/bfd33934-43f2-4d71-bfe4-d89f01a8c0f9"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.tablet.tabletweb",
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "AIzaSyBNWwM2b8bnh5mXJFk7_DhDb87yhqOnuZM"
        }
      },
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/icon/appstore.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png"
    },
    "androidStatusBar": {
      "hidden": true
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "bfd33934-43f2-4d71-bfe4-d89f01a8c0f9"
      }
    },
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "nativeVersion"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "ProguardInReleaseBuilds": true
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "plugins": [
    [
      "expo-media-library",
      {
        "photosPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your photos.",
        "savePhotosPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to save photos.",
        "isAccessMediaLocationEnabled": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "devtools": "react-devtools",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@actbase/react-daum-postcode": "^1.0.4",
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~6.0.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.0.1",
    "@hauvo/react-native-360-image-viewer": "^1.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.7.3",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.4.2",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/elements": "^1.3.18",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.5",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.25",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.2.0",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-asset": "~8.9.1",
    "expo-av": "~13.2.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.6.0",
    "expo-camera": "~13.2.1",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.3.1",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.2.1",
    "expo-device": "~5.2.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-intent-launcher": "~10.5.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.1.2",
    "expo-linking": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-location": "~15.1.1",
    "expo-media-library": "~15.2.3",
    "expo-navigation-bar": "~2.1.1",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~5.1.1",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.1.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.16.4",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "jsencrypt": "^3.3.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "nanoid": "^4.0.2",
    "patch-package": "^7.0.2",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-bouncy-checkbox": "^3.0.7",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-error-boundary": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-redash": "^18.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-signature-canvas": "^4.5.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-view-shot": "3.5.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.10",
    "react-native-webview": "11.26.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-observable": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.5",
    "typesafe-actions": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.9",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.2.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.195",
    "@types/mime": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.27",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.1",
    "jest-expo": "^48.0.1",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I attempted various solutions, including using the expo-web-browser module for document downloads. I expected the WebView-based document downloads to work both in Expo Go and the built app (APK, Android). However, the actual result is that while document downloads succeed in Expo Go, they fail in the built app despite successful API communication.